# cerberus - how to validate arbitrary dict keys?

Tags: python, cerberus

I have read issues [here](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues/91) and [here](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/issues/237) using keysrules and valuesrules but I've only seen them validate nested not root. I'd like to valid the top level root dict keys.

```
schema = {
    'any_arbitrary_str': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'keysrules': {'type': 'string'},
        'valuesrules': {'type': 'integer'},
    },
}

v = Validator(schema)
v.validate({'test': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}})
print(v.errors)
```

In this example, I'd like to just validate that schema is dict of `str: Dict[str, int]` where the keys can be any arbitrary string.

I'm not sure I'm using it right [docs](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#keysrules), this fails with `cerberus.schema.SchemaError: {'any_arbitrary_str': [{'keysrules': ['unknown rule'], 'valuesrules': ['unknown rule']}]}` but it's still looking for `any_arbitrary_str` instead of any string also.

Comment: If you want to apply to the root, nest it! ;-)

Comment: Or switch to jsonschema.

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest it. Not pretty, but works. I have not found a more elegant solution yet.

```py
schema = {
    'document': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'keysrules': {'type': 'string'},
        'valuesrules': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'keysrules': {'type': 'string'},
            'valuesrules': {'type': 'integer'},
        },
    },
}

v = Validator(schema)
document_to_test = {'test': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}

v.validate({'document': document_to_test})
print(v.errors)
```